# How to change AJAX response HTML and then continue replacemant in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an AJAX that gets new HTML and replaces the form data in response.html.  There is one attribute that I need changed before the replacement.

Here is my try but I cant get it right:

```
success: function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (response.data.html !== null) {
        var newdata = response.data.html;
        if(firstload == 1){
            var newhtml  = $(newdata).find('.trigger').attr('data-firstload',0);
            // now I need to replace newdata
        }
        $(container).html(newdata); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose response already IS the html string. JQuery works with DOM elements, not an html string. You need regex or shadow dom technics to do what you want, I guess.

Comment: `$(container).empty().append( $(newdata) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a jQuery object containing the new HTML, update it, then append it. Try this:

```
success: function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (response.data.html !== null) {
        var $newHtml = $(response.data.html);

        if (firstload == 1)
            $newHtml.find('.trigger').attr('data-firstload', 0);

        $(container).empty().append($newHtml);
    }
},
```